# Create groups based on z score R

Tags: r

I have a very large data set for which I want to convert the numeric values into categories. 
I have computed the z scores for each column and I wanted to find out if there was an easier way to assign groups without nested if statements.

the groups I have defined are:

```
1 = z score(x) <= -3   
2 =  z score(x) <=- 2.5  
3 = z score(x) <= 2  
.  
.  
12 = z score(x) <= 2.5  
13 = z score(x) <= 3 
14 = z score(x) >3
```

I can do this by nested if statements but just want to get some ideas if there is a faster way?

Thanks

Comment: `meanVal + (seq(-3, 3, .5) * SD)` will create a vector of cutoff points, then use `cut`.

Comment: I think that you actually need `c(-Inf, meanVal + (seq(-3, 3, .5) * SD), Inf)` as the break points

Comment: thanks, realised as I already have z score I don't need to use meanVal.
'cut(x,breaks=c(-Inf, seq(-3, 3, .5), Inf),labels = c(1:14))'